# How to maximise the parallel efficiency of siesta?

Tags: high-performance-computing, siesta

Are there any options I should optimize in the input file to maximize the parallel efficiency? Like in the VASP, there are two options `NCORE` and `KPAR` controlling how to configure parallel running.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of levels of parallelism:

1. For big systems the general rule of thumb is that the diagonalization is the bottleneck for the Siesta calculation. Here, only one flag exists for optimizing the parallel efficiency:

```
Diag.ParallelOverK true
```

By default, Siesta uses all cores to diagonalize every k-point. However, if the system is "small", but you have many k-points, say $N_k>N_{processors}$, then using `Diag.ParallelOverK` might improve efficiency significantly.

2. Another part is the grid, generally this is very well parallelised and there is not much to gain, the defaults are standardly good.